# Load npy file from S3 in python

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3

is there anyway to load/read an external file(i.e, AWS S3) in numpy?. I have several npy files stored in S3. I have tried to access them through a S3 presigned url but it seems neither numpy.load method or np.genfromtxt are able to read them.

I wouldn't want to save files on local file system and then load them on numpy.

Any idea?

Comment: Of course you need some extra-layer doing all the web-protocol work! Numpy's IO is probably designed for file-based IO only. In Python3, you could try ```import request; import BytesIO; request = requests.get(url); np.load(BytesIO(request.content))```.

Comment: Of course my snippet is assuming the S3-link is a public one without the need for authentication. I don't know if that's the case. If not, you would need some library doing this auth for accessing the files!

Comment: Are you able to read the files using `requests`?

Comment: Hi, wasn't able to read. Finally, I'm using spark textFiles that makes it possible. thx!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/)

```py
import numpy as np
from s3fs.core import S3FileSystem
s3 = S3FileSystem()

key = 'your_file.npy'
bucket = 'your_bucket'

df = np.load(s3.open('{}/{}'.format(bucket, key)))
```

You might have to set the `allow_pickle=True` depending on your file to be read.

Answer (score 6):

I've compared s3fs and io.BytesIO for loading a 28G npz file from s3. s3fs takes 30 min while io takes 12 min.

```
obj = s3_session.resource("s3").Object(bucket, key)
with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as f:
    f.seek(0)  # rewind the file
    X, y = np.load(f).values()
```

```
s3fs = S3FileSystem()
with s3fs.open(f"s3://{bucket}/{key}") as s3file:
     X, y = np.load(s3file).values()
```

Comment: s3fs is really slow even for a few npys

Answer (score 1):

I had success using [boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html) and StringIO.
Connect to S3 using boto and get your bucket. Then read the file with following code into numpy:

```
  import numpy as np
  from StringIO import StringIO
  key=bucket.get_key('YOUR_KEY')
  data_string=StringIO(key.get_contents_as_string())
  data = np.load(data_string)
```

I am not sure it's the most efficient way, but it doesn't require a public URL.

Cheers,
Michael